# Перезагрузка внешнего скрипта в nextjs при смене URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs, next.js

Есть компонент который должен выводить баннер на страницах SSG.
Проблема в том что при первой загрузке (или перезагрузки страницы) скрипт отрабатывает отлично и выводит текст на странице "тест баннера XX" и в консоль "Script has loaded v.XXXXX", но при переходе на другие страницы в консоли ошибка: **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'bannerDiv' has already been declared"**.

Функция `handleRouteChange` при переходе по страницам тоже отлично отрабатывает и выводит корректно *"URL изменен на XX v.1671094719667"*.

Пользоваться полной перезагрузкой страницы, теряется весь смысл и преимущества NEXTJS.
Но как реализовать принудительную перезагрузку только внешнего скрипта при смене URL?

Компонент баннера подгружается Dynamic Import https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

```
import { Suspense } from 'react'
import dynamic      from "next/dynamic"    
const UnderMap = dynamic(() => import("@components/bannerScripts/UnderMap"), { ssr:false })
...
return (
...
    <Suspense 
        fallback={`Загрузка...`}
    >
        <UnderMap />
    </Suspense>
)
```

Сам компонент UnderMap:

```
import { useEffect }    from 'react'
import { useRouter }    from 'next/router'
import Script           from 'next/script'

export default function UnderMap({ }) {

const router = useRouter();
const unique_id = new Date().getTime();

const handleRouteChange = (url) => {
    console.log(`URL изменен на ${url} v.${unique_id}`)
}

useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange)
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange)
    }
}, [])

// debugger;
return (
<>
    <div 
        id="underMap" 
        className="d-none my-3"
    >   
        по умолчанию скрыт
    </div>
    <Script 
        src={`https://ВНЕШНЯЯ_ССЫЛКА/_r/underMap.js?cacheControl=${unique_id}`} 
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        onLoad={() => {
            console.log(`Script has loaded v.${unique_id}`)
        }}
    />
</>
)
}
```

Скрипт underMap.js

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
    let rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
    return Math.floor(rand);
}

const bannerDiv = document.querySelector("div#underMap");
bannerDiv.classList.remove('d-none')
bannerDiv.innerHTML = (`тест баннера ${randomInteger(1, 100)}`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда прогружается ваш скрипт, он в глобальной области создает переменную **bannerDiv**. При повторной загрузке скрипта, вы логично, получаете сообщение об ошибке, т.к. переменная уже создана.

Обойти это можно, обернув создание переменной и установку значений в функцию:

**underMap.js**

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  let rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
  return Math.floor(rand);
}

function showBanner() {
  const bannerDiv = document.querySelector("div#underMap");
  bannerDiv.classList.remove('d-none')
  bannerDiv.innerHTML = (`тест баннера ${randomInteger(1, 100)}`)  
}

showBanner();
```

Или обернуть все в анонимную функцию, что бы изолировать свои функции и переменные от внешнего окружения

```
(() => {
  function randomInteger(min, max) {
    let rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
    return Math.floor(rand);
  }

  const bannerDiv = document.querySelector("div#underMap");
  bannerDiv.classList.remove('d-none')
  bannerDiv.innerHTML = (`тест баннера ${randomInteger(1, 100)}`)
})();
```

Не знаю вашу идею, но мутирование DOM в React приложении не силами React, это очень плохая практика.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло обернуть создание переменной и установить значений в функцию.

Это не моя задумка. Это будут внешние скрипты от рекламодателей. 
Просто получается от них загружается баннер и пользователь может посмотреть 10 страниц, а баннер не перегружается и получается только один показ.

Comment: @Yauheniy Я бы все равно рекомендовал бы подумать над тем, как это можно сделать исключительно силами React и next